# How to join two table without null data

Tags: sql, join, left-join, union, qsqlquery

I have two table named **demoa** and **demob** containing both same field ID and Name. For ex :

Demoa table containing data like

```
| Id | Name   |
| 1  | divya  |
| 2  | saumya |
| 3  | urvasi |
```

Demob table containing data like

```
| Id | Name  |
| 1  | karan |
| 2  | rekha |
| 3  | bhavna|
| 4  | bindu |
```

now when I merge both table its output coming like this with the latest query

```
| demoa | demob |
| divya |       |
| saumya|       | 
| urvasi|       |
|       | karan |
|       | rekha |
|       | bhavna|
|       | bindu |
```

here is the query

```
select a.name as demoa, '' as demob from demoa a
union all
select '', name from demob b
```

But I want output like this

```
| demoa | demob |
| divya | karan |
| saumya| rekha | 
| urvasi| bhavna|
|       | bindu |
```

I used **join** query also but didnt work for me

Comment: It sounds like you need `FULL OUTER JOIN` - assuming your DB supports it.

Comment: can you show me code syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT A.ID,A.NAME,B.ID,B.NAME
 FROM DEMOA AS A
 FULL JOIN DEMOB AS B ON A.ID=B.ID
```